# Editing __doc__ within a flat method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a super thin cli wrapper around an api I wrote. It seems like the `__doc__` dunder attr is set at import time.

```
>>> def foo():
...     """
...     doc
...     """
...     pass
...
>>> foo.__doc__
'\n\tdoc\n\t'
```

I found that I can change the `__doc__` within the method

```
>>> def foo():
...     foo.__doc__ = "new doc"
...
>>> foo.__doc__
>>> foo()
>>> foo.__doc__
'new doc'
```

But this requires the method to be run.

I am writing a [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) tool and this allows `file.py --help` to print the doc. However, because this is a thin wrapper, it would be nice to just edit the `__doc__` to be the same as the doc whatever method it calls internally.

> API.py

```
class FOO:
    def bar():
        """
        Some long doc string
        """
        pass
```

> cli.py

```
import click

import API

@click.command()
def hello():
    """
    not what I want
    """
    hello.__doc__ = API.FOO.bar.__doc__
    API.FOO.bar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(hello.__doc__)
    hello()
    print(API.FOO.bar.__doc__)
```

I get the below... when running `pyhton3.6 cli.py`

```
not what I want


Some long doc string
```

And when I run `python3.6 cli.py --help`

```
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS]

  not what I want

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Is there any way to inject the doc string from the imported method into the click method? Maybe a decorator resolves at import time but I am not sure how that might be done. Thanks.

Comment: You can change the function's `__doc__` attribute from the outside, actually from everywhere where you have a reference to the function.

Comment: @KlausD hm so I would need to do it outside the method... like @changeDoc(API.FOO.bar) decorator that takes a method to get the doc from and decorates a method to change the doc for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the change to doc as a  decorator on your function it will run at import time.

```
def change_doc(function):
        function.__doc__="my text"
        return function
```

Comment: Is there any fancy way for the decorator to know what the function is calling and use that __doc__ or do I need to explicitly pass the decorator the method to get the doc from?

Comment: I edited, although I'm not in front of a computer so may not be perfect

Answer (score 1):

So the general idea is that you want to be able to take `API.FOO.bar` and make a named wrapper for it. No problem, although it takes a bit of out-of-box thinking. The key idea here is to understand that decorators can also be used as normal functions, transforming one function into another:

```
def wrap_api(method):
    result = click.command(method)
    result.__doc__ = method.__doc__
    return method
```

And now we can create our wrappers:

```
hello = wrap_api(API.FOO.bar)
```